# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in D:\POforWork\Ampps\www\news\app\database\db.php on line 30

Tags: php, база-данных, синтаксис

```
    <?php
    
    require 'connect.php';
    
    function test($value){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($value);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    
    function selectAll($table){
        global $pdo;    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $errInfo = $query->errorInfo();
    
        if($errInfo[0] !== PDO::ERR_NONE){
            echo $errInfo[2];
            exit();
        }
    
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
    
    test(selectAll(table:'users'));
```

как сделать чтобы в последней строке не было ошибки?
'users' - это таблица в БД

Comment: что это `table:'users'` ?

Answer (score 2):

Надо убрать слово `table:`. Потому что вы наверное копировали текст из видео. А там используют другую версию *PHP* (PHP 8 **[именованные аргументы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments)**), в которой разрешено указание именованных аргументов или показаны подсказки *IDE* (более вероятно)

Comment: Спасибо, работает