# Не подключается база данных mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Делал все точь-в-точь как на видео, но выдает ошибку:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 5

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect( host: 'localhost', user: 'root', password: '', database: 'first');

if (!$connect) {
    echo 'Error';
 }
?>
```

[image: видео]

Comment: Во-первых, неплохо бы для начала посмотреть синтаксис php не по видео, а по книжке или статьям. Во-вторых, IDE, которую использует автор, добавляет некоторый текст в код визуально, но фактически его там нет, что вы и видите (например `host: `)

Comment: а ты уверен что у тебя сам MySQL настроен???

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1411521/191482

Comment: @ArchDemon Для 8+ это уже не было бы ошибкой, стоит добавить..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$connect = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'first');